# How do I Install bundled interface dependencies with modern CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, dependency-management, packaging, cmake-modules

What is the proper way to install bundled interface dependencies in Modern CMake?

I have a library `MyLib` that has an interface dependency on `libDep` (`MyLib.hpp` contains `#include <libDep.h>`). Anything that depends on `MyLib` also transitively depends on `libDep`.

`libDep` is a single header taken from a gist so I have included it part of the source-tree of `MyLib`

```
$ tree
.
├── CMake
│   ├── MyLibConfig.cmake.in
│   └── modules
│       └── FindlibDep.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── MyLib
│       └── MyLib.hpp
├── src
│   └── MyLib.cpp
└── third_party
    └── libDep
        └── libDep.h
```

I would like to install `libDep` with `myLib`, in with a path like `include/MyLib/third_party/libDep`.

---

Here is the CMakeLists for `MyLib`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3.0)
Project(MyLib
    DESCRIPTION "Library with bundled interface dependency"
    LANGUAGES CXX)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/modules)

# Find LibDep dependency
find_package(libDep REQUIRED)

# MyLib library
add_library(MyLib STATIC
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyLib.cpp)

target_include_directories(MyLib
    PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MyLib>
    PUBLIC $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/MyLib>)

target_link_libraries(MyLib
    INTERFACE libDep)
```

`MyLib` locates `libDep` with `FindlibDep.cmake` located in `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`

```
find_path(LibDep_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES LibDep.hpp
    PATHS third_party/libDep)
    PATH_SUFFIXES Mylib/third_party/libDep)

mark_as_advanced(LibDep_FOUND LibDep_INCLUDE_DIR)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(LibDep
    REQUIRED_VARS
        LibDep_INCLUDE_DIR
)

if(LibDep_FOUND)
    set(LibDep_INCLUDE_DIRS ${LibDep_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

if(LibDep_FOUND AND NOT TARGET MyLib::LibDep)
    add_library(MyLib::LibDep INTERFACE IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(MyLib::LibDep PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${LibDep_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()
```

---

I install `MyLib` like

```
install(TARGETS MyLib
    EXPORT MyLibTargets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    INCLUDES DESTINATION include)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(MyLibConfigVersion.cmake)

install(EXPORT MyLibTargets
    FILE MyLibTargets.cmake
    NAMESPACE MyLib::
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/MyLib)

configure_file(CMake/MyLibConfig.cmake.in MyLibConfig.cmake @ONLY)
install(FILES
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibConfig.cmake"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibConfigVersion.cmake"
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/MyLib)

install(DIRECTORY ${MyLib_PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIR}
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

# Package with CPack
include(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)
include(CPack)
```

`MyLibConfig.cmake.in` declares a dependency on `libDep`

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

# Dependencies
add_library(libDep REQUIRED)

# Add the targets file
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/MyLibTargets.cmake")
```

`libDep` is installed into `MyLib`'s tree with

```
install(DIRECTORY ${libDep_INCLUDE_DIRS}
DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/MyLib/third_party)
```

and I copy the find module with

```
install(FILES
    ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/FindlibDep.cmake
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/MyLib)
```

---

Unfortunately users of `MyLib` don't see `FindlibDep.cmake` by default

```
$ cmake ..
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:48 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindlibDep.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "libDep", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libDep" with any
  of the following names:

    libDepConfig.cmake
    libDep-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "libDep" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "libDep_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "libDep"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/MyLib/MyLibConfig.cmake:5 (find_dependency)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The user can manually locate `FindlibDep.cmake` and add it to their `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` but that shouldn't be required.

---

A reproduction of this issue is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/WesToleman/StackOverflow-52591766).

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the PROJECT_ variable for the source dir instead of the CMAKE_ variable:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/modules)
```

PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR gets the source dir from the most recently executed project() directive (in this case, your library).

You should also be adding your current CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to the new path, as shown above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Karl! Unfornatelt it didn't solve my issue. I'm not sure if I described my situation well enough so I've added [a repository reproducing the issue](https://github.com/WesToleman/StackOverflow-52591766) to GitHub.